# Does setting FeedOptions.EnableCrossPartitionQuery to false need to be combined with FeedOptions.PartitionKey?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I want to send a document query using:

```
var query = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<ArticleEntity>(collectionLink, feedOptions)
    .Where(entity => entity.Type == someType)
    .AsDocumentQuery();
```

In the `FeedOptions` it is possible to set `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` to false to only query a single partition.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.enablecrosspartitionquery?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_FeedOptions_EnableCrossPartitionQuery) it says:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether users are enabled to send more
>   than one request to execute the query in the Azure Cosmos DB service.
>   More than one request is necessary if the query is not scoped to
>   single partition key value.

So I am not sure how to interpret *"query is not scoped to single partition key value"*.

Do I need to also set the partition key to make sure the "query is scoped" properly or will the SDK automatically determine the partition key from my entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you also need to specify the partition key explicitly, using [`FeedOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions?view=azure-dotnet) and its [`PartitionKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.partitionkey?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_FeedOptions_PartitionKey) property as you've noted. Here's an example:

```
feedOptions.PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("yourPartitionKey");

var query = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<ArticleEntity>(collectionLink, feedOptions)
    .Where(entity => entity.Type == someType)
    .AsDocumentQuery();
```

It is setting the `PartitionKey` property that *scopes the query to a single partition*.

Comment: Do you know what the behavior is if only one of the properties is set? e.g. If I don't send the partition key but only disable cross partitioning?

Comment: From what I remember, if you do that it'll thrown an exception explaining that the partition key is required.

Comment: Just for completeness, I tested this and the comment above is correct.